# How to develop a type with a condition?

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements

For example

```
struct Condition
{
    template<class T>
    static bool check(T const& t) {...} // option 1

    template<class T>
    bool operator()(T const& t) {...} // or option 2
};

template<class T, class Condition>
class A
{
   T m_t;

   void f()
   {
       Condition::check(m_t); // option 1
       Condition()(m_t); // or option 2
   }
};
```

I am wondering which option has a better performance? I think option 1 is better because it doesn't need to generate a temporary object `Condition()`. But usually I saw option 2. Or any other better ways?

Comment: I'm putting my bet on "no difference whatsoever". Compilers are amazing, you know :)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully get what you're asking about. But option 2 allows to use the class as a functor, and hence makes it usable for standard algorithms.

Comment: The decision of which one to use shouldn't be about what is faster, but what is clearer. Overloading `operator()` should only be done if the meaning of calling the class is obvious.

Comment: How much work do you think it is to "generate a temporary"?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a [predicate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Predicate)

In your context they are the same, because you are making a direct call.
Even if you make an indirect call I suspect that for the static function the function is still uniquely resolved, but I am not 100% sure.

But a function object (a struct with operator()) is usually the most safe, general and efficient for a compiler if you pass it to a callback, so prefer this as a general rule if you are going to use your comparator as a callback:

```
 struct F {
     bool operator()(T const & t) const {}
 };
```

So if you do:

```
 std::partition(begin(a), end(a), F{}); //F{} is the predicate callback
```

it is very likely that it will be more efficient than

```
 void f(T const & t); 
 std::sort(begin(a), end(a), &f);
```

Comment: imho thats a bit too handywavy. Why is it very likely that a functor will be more efficient? Rules are only worth as much as one knows when to apply them and when not. Blindly following a rule is very bad practice imho